# Stripe presentWithSetupIntent does not show the PaymentSheet for SetupIntents

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I've tested the Stripe's PaymentSheet for PaymentIntents, passing the payment intent client secret, the customer id and the ephemeral key.
I succeeded on closing a payment, both with and without the bank verification step.

I'm trying to use the `SetupIntent` because I need to authorize now a payment but to bill users in the future. So I've generated a scheduled subscription for a customer and obtained a setup intent client secret.

My problem is, when I call

```
paymentSheet.presentWithSetupIntent(
    setupIntentClientSecret,
    PaymentSheet.Configuration(
        merchantDisplayName = Constants.MERCHANT,
        customer = PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration(
            customerId,
            ephemeralKeySecret
        )
    )
)
```

I see the payment sheet coming out from the bottom with only an infinite progress bar, as if the setup intent was invalid.

Comment: Are there any errors in logcat or in your Stripe API logs (https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs) when this happens?

Comment: SetupIntents are currently not supported in Android PaymentSheet integration, it looks like the mobile SDK team at Stripe will have to mark that as an internal function for now.

Comment: Yes, I've opened an issue on their GitHub and they answered me the same thing: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/3744